# Failing to register FoxPro 6 made DLL on Win 8.1 but it registers fine on Win 7

Tags: visual-c++, dll, registry, windows-8.1, visual-foxpro

**Summary:** Having two testing FoxPro made DLLs (one FoxPro 6, the other by FoxPro 9 -- see the code below), two compilers (VC++ 2010 and VC++ 2015), two machines (Windows 7 and Windows 8.1), and one C++ source with code that should register the DLLs (see below). The FoxPro 6 DLL fails to register on Windows 8.1; however, it registers fine on Windows 7.

(See the note about the later discovery with `regsvr32`. However, the C++ code explains where it fails.)

**Details:** Both machines are in LAN, user logged to the same domain. Both C++ project does the static linking (Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)) to eliminate problems with missing runtime, both use the UAC Execution Level `requireAdministrator`.

The code for the FoxPro DLL (the FoxPro 9 version only returns 9 instead):

```
DEFINE CLASS APSfoxTestClass AS CUSTOM OLEPUBLIC
    PROCEDURE DllVersion()
        RETURN 6
    ENDPROC
ENDDEFINE
```

The C++ code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool RegisterDll(std::string DllName)
{
    // LoadLibrary() requires backslashes.
    replace(DllName.begin(), DllName.end(), '/', '\\');

    HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(DllName.c_str());
    if (hLib == 0)
        return false;

    // Find the DllRegisterServer entry point, and call the function.
    FARPROC lpDllEntryPoint = GetProcAddress(hLib, TEXT("DllRegisterServer"));
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;   // pessimistic initialization

    if (lpDllEntryPoint != 0)
        hr = (*lpDllEntryPoint)(); // <----- here it fails for apsfoxtest.dll
                                   // but it is OK for apsfoxtest9.dll

    // Release the library.
    if (hLib != 0)
        FreeLibrary(hLib);

    // Return the status (success) of the call.
    return hr == S_OK;
}


bool UnregisterDll(std::string DllName)
{
    replace(DllName.begin(), DllName.end(), '/', '\\');
    HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(DllName.c_str());
    if (hLib == 0)
        return false;

    FARPROC lpDllEntryPoint = GetProcAddress(hLib, TEXT("DllUnregisterServer"));
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    if (lpDllEntryPoint != 0)
        hr = (*lpDllEntryPoint)();

    if (hLib != 0)
        FreeLibrary(hLib);

    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}


int main()
{
    HRESULT hRes = CoInitialize(0);

    string dllname("apsfoxtest9.dll");
    cout << "Registering " << dllname << " ... ";
    bool isOK = RegisterDll(dllname);
    cout << (isOK ? "OK" : "Failed") << endl;

    cout << "Unregistering " << dllname << " ...";
    isOK = UnregisterDll(dllname);
    cout << (isOK ? "OK" : "Failed") << endl;

    cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";

    dllname = "apsfoxtest.dll";
    cout << "Registering " << dllname << " ... ";
    isOK = RegisterDll(dllname);
    cout << (isOK ? "OK" : "Failed") << endl;

    cout << "Unregistering " << dllname << " ... ";
    isOK = UnregisterDll(dllname);
    cout << (isOK ? "OK" : "Failed") << endl;

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The VC++ 2015 binary was compiled on Win 8.1 machine (a newer machine, a newer compiler), but works fine on Win 7 machine for both versions of DLL. The VC++ 2010 was compiled on Win 7 machine. Both executables work fine for FoxPro 9 DLL on both Win 8.1 and Win 7, both executables fail on Win 8.1 when registering the FoxPro 6 DLL.

When debugging (it was possible only for VC++ 2015 on Win 8.1) the execution fails when calling the `DllRegisterServer` code (at the line marked by the comment) with the *Access violation* exception see the end of the tail from the Output window:

```
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\__Cpp\__pepr\20150903\apsfoxtest9.dll'
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\__Cpp\__pepr\20150903\apsfoxtest.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\__Cpp\__pepr\20150903\VFP6R.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
'test_regsvr.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\__Cpp\__pepr\20150903\VFP6RENU.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown at 0x0C00D2BF (VFP6R.DLL) in test_regsvr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

**Later found:** The `regsvr32 apsfoxtest.dll` called from the `cmd` launched *as administrator* probably also fails (the final message box with the success message does not appear).

**May be related:** We have observed a possibly related problem when the application that used the FoxPro 6 DLL was executed on Windows servers. It failed because of the DEP mechanism (Data Execution Prevention). The DEP exception for the application had to be added.

Do you have similar experience with FoxPro 6 and the Windows 8.1? Can the FoxPro 6 DLL be fixed somehow?

Comment: Do you have the right runtimes? Specifically, I'm thinking of the right VC runtime. VFP 9 calls for msvcr71.dll. VFP 6 needs an earlier version; it's probably the VC 6 version, but I'm not sure. I know that VFP 6 uses msvcr70.dll.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor: Good hint! I still haven't solve it, but the truth is that msvcr for VFP6 runtime did not come to my mind. I makes sense as at least on one Windows 10 machine the code works. So, the problem might be related to specifically my machine. I tried to add msvcr70.dll, but it did not help. Searching...

Comment: Are both machines running 64 bit operating system?

Comment: @Caltor, frankly, it was quite a time ago :) The project is dormant now. We have returned to the FoxPro 6 version, and it is still occasionally maintained on the machine with VC++ 2010.